# SQL want Repeated result NULL from one table

Tags: sql, postgresql

hi i have problem in sql query example

Employee

```
empid  empname
1      gan
2      sam
```

Designation

```
id        desig            empid
1      sr officerr          1
2      jr officer           1
3      manager              2
```

i want join tables and want Employee Table repeated records Null

```
result like

empid     name     desig            id
1         gan      sr officerr      1
1         NULL     jr officer       2
2         sam      manager          3
```

i working on query but i not getting result

```
SELECT DISTINCT designatin.empid, employee.empname,designatin.desig 
FROM designatin INNER JOIN employee e ON employee.empid = designatin.empid 
GROUP BY employee.empid, employee.empname, designatin.desig
```

can anybody have solution?

Comment: Didn't you post this just one hour ago? (Or was it someone else in same class?)

Comment: @jarlh you had solution that time?

Comment: @Ganeshp:- just I dont understand, why you have null in name column in expected result while you have name in table?

Comment: @Piyush i want fetch result to jasper report

Answer (score 0):

Change the inner join to a left join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT designatin.empid, employee.empname,designatin.desig 
FROM designatin LEFT JOIN employee e ON employee.empid = designatin.empid 
GROUP BY employee.empid, employee.empname, designatin.desig
```

Comment: i tried but get repeated records from employee table

Comment: Do you have more than one record for any employee in the designation table? If yes, you will get duplicates. Try SELECT count(*), empid FROM designation GROUP BY empid HAVING count(*) >1. And if an employee can have only one designation, shouldn't we have designation id in emp table and not the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

Let try this, it will help you

```
SELECT e.empid, e.empname,d.desig ,d.id
FROM employee  e
INNER JOIN  Designation d  ON e.empid = d.empid
```

See [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5836/1)

Comment: i tried but get repeated records from employee table